# numpy.linespace and uneven spacing between bins

Tags: python, numpy

im using numpy.linespace to help generate bins for data.
I want 20 bins between 0 and 1,000,000, each 20k in size.

numpy.linespace is giving uneven bin sizes.

```
bins = np.linspace(start = 0, stop =1000000, num = 50, dtype = 'int64')
```

This gives bins like below (first 5 bins)

```
2.040800000000000000e+04
,4.081600000000000000e+04
,6.122400000000000000e+04
,8.163200000000000000e+04
,1.020400000000000000e+05
```

Any idea how to get the the even bins 20000,40000,60000,80000,1000000

Thanks for any help and advice

Comment: `np.linspace(20000, 1000000, 50)` Should do the trick

Comment: `linspace`, by default includes the end point.  So you need to take that into account with specifying the count.  And even so, specifying the `int` dtype can be tricky.  `linspace` calculates with floats, and then truncates.  `arange` may be safer if you want integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one to the number o samples

```
>>> bins = np.linspace(start = 0, stop = 1000000, num = 51, dtype = 'int64')
>>> bins
array([ 0,   20000,   40000,   60000,   80000,  100000,  120000,
    140000,  160000,  180000,  200000,  220000,  240000,  260000,
    280000,  300000,  320000,  340000,  360000,  380000,  400000,
    420000,  440000,  460000,  480000,  500000,  520000,  540000,
    560000,  580000,  600000,  620000,  640000,  660000,  680000,
    700000,  720000,  740000,  760000,  780000,  800000,  820000,
    840000,  860000,  880000,  900000,  920000,  940000,  960000,
    980000, 1000000])
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! pardon my ignorance, but i dont understand why this works.

Comment: This instruction is designed to generate num numbers in the range [start,stop] equally distributed. So if you want to generate numbers from 0 to 3 (0,1,2,3) you have to have 4(3+1) numbers.

Answer (score 0):

With `arange` instead of `linspace`:

```
In [456]: np.arange(0,1000001,20000)
Out[456]: 
array([      0,   20000,   40000,   60000,   80000,  100000,  120000,
        140000,  160000,  180000,  200000,  220000,  240000,  260000,
        280000,  300000,  320000,  340000,  360000,  380000,  400000,
        420000,  440000,  460000,  480000,  500000,  520000,  540000,
        560000,  580000,  600000,  620000,  640000,  660000,  680000,
        700000,  720000,  740000,  760000,  780000,  800000,  820000,
        840000,  860000,  880000,  900000,  920000,  940000,  960000,
        980000, 1000000])
In [457]: _.shape
Out[457]: (51,)
```

`arange` does not include the end point, so that's why I added the 1.  `linspace` includes the end point (but that can be turned off), but produces floats by default.